# ServiceStack Ormlite transaction between services

Tags: sql-server, transactions, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having trouble with a rather complex save operation inside a ServiceStack service. 
To simplify the explanation the service starts an Ormlite transaction and within it calls another service through ResolveService:

```
public ApplicationModel Post(ApplicationModel request)
{
    using (IDbTransaction tr = Db.OpenTransaction())
    {
        using (var cases = ResolveService<CaseService>())
        {
            request.Case = cases.Post(request.Case);
        }
    }
    Db.Save<Application>(request.Application, true);
}
```

The other service (CaseService) uses also a transaction to perform its logic:

```
public CaseModel Post(CaseModel request)
{
    using (IDbTransaction tr = Db.OpenTransaction())
    {
        Db.Insert<Case>(request);
        Db.SaveAllReferences<CaseModel>(request);
    }
}
```

In a similar situation with higher hierarchy of services calling other services a "Timeout expired" error is thrown, and so far I've not been able to resolve, although I closely monitored the SQL Server for deadlocks.

My question is whether this is the right way of using/sharing Ormlite transactions across services or there is another mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have nested transactions, rather than calling across services to perform DB operations you should extract shared logic out either using a separate [shared Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26291393/85785) or re-usable extension methods:

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static void SaveCaseModel(this IDbConnection db,
        CaseModel case)
    {
        db.Insert<Case>(case);
        db.SaveAllReferences<CaseModel>(case);
    }
}
```

Then your Services can maintain their own transactions whilst being able to share logic, e.g:

```
public ApplicationModel Post(ApplicationModel request)
{
    using (var trans = Db.OpenTransaction())
    {
        Db.SaveCaseModel(request.Case);
        Db.Save<Application>(request.Application, true);
        trans.Commit();
    }
}

public CaseModel Post(CaseModel request)
{
    using (var trans = Db.OpenTransaction())
    {
        Db.SaveCaseModel(request);
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, actually in the services there is more than just database operations, there is also reusable logic that is requested from other services as well as from the client. I would need to transfer it on the shared repository. Can I share a transaction between services? What about OrmliteConfig.TSTransaction?

Comment: @gjspaho Sure, you can share the same transaction just structure it so it avoids nesting transactions.

Comment: What would be the best way of sharing the transaction?

Comment: @gjspaho Just open the transaction at the top-level entry-point API and don't nest them, i.e. any shared logic shouldn't start it's own transaction. Any DB operations within the scope of a transaction are implicitly apart of that transaction.

Comment: How can I test whether an opened transaction exists, the injected dbconnection's transaction of the service is always null.

Comment: @gjspaho It needs to be cast to `OrmLiteConnection`, but this test shows [Transaction isn't null](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/ea010fee3c4743ce70add0af17862b7e3ca510a0/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/OrmLiteTransactionTests.cs#L26), but otherwise it's your code so you should know if you've opened a transaction or not.

Comment: @mythz We have some code that is similar to the poster and for some reason only started seeing a "Connection must be valid and open" after upgrading to v4.0.46 (from v4.0.36) Are you able to explain why we would be seeing it now in 4.0.46 and not in the earlier version? Has the logic for ResolveService changed? Would be good to know as this could potentially impact many parts of our app.